# KernelCheck inexplicably crashes during information retrieval

Tags: linux, crash

I'm using [KernelCheck](http://kcheck.sourceforge.net/) on Ubuntu oneiric and when I start it up, after entering the root password, I click on the button that reads "Get Kernel Information" and then it simply crashes. I have a snapshot of the program here in its frozen state (you can notice that the button is pressed down). Sometimes it gets up to 25%  of the info download and crashes there but it's never got passed that. Could it have anything to do with the fact that the official [Kernel site](http://www.kernel.org) (where KC gets its info from) [recently got hacked](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/blogs/browse/2011/08/cracking-kernelorg)? I think this is unlikely, but anyway the program's not running.

[image: KernelCheck is frozen]

Answer (score 0):

Try running it by the terminal:

```
sudo kernelcheck
```

This works for building linux 2.6 kernels.

though the author is currently in the  ürocess of a new version to build the 3.0 kernels.

[Kernelcheck](http://kernelcheck.blogspot.com/2011/07/its-alive.html) has some more info if you are interested.